# Scroll to given position in Android Leanback ListRow

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I'm using the Google Leanback widgets in an Android TV application. It utilizes a RowsFragment with ListRows in it.

What I'm trying to determine is if there is any way to programmatically scroll to a particular object within one of the rows.  I've dug into the docs for the Leanback widgets but cannot find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar necessity: I needed to set the initial selected item in a ListRow.
I ended up subclassing the ListRowPresenter like this:

```
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ListRowPresenter;
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.RowPresenter;

public class CustomPresenter extends ListRowPresenter {

    private int mInitialSelectedPosition;

    public CustomPresenter(int position) {
        this.mInitialSelectedPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindRowViewHolder(RowPresenter.ViewHolder holder, Object item) {
        super.onBindRowViewHolder(holder, item);

        ViewHolder vh = (ListRowPresenter.ViewHolder) holder;
        vh.getGridView().setSelectedPosition(mInitialSelectedPosition);
    }

}
```

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I think that gives me the information I'll need to do what I wanted.

Comment: The example is really good, it is also possible to modify the logic behind the first item to select. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

In the latest version of Leanback (think v23.3.0+), you can now specify not only the row position but also perform optional tasks on the row. In your case, the task would be programmatic selection like so:

`BrowseFragment.setSelectedPosition(0, true, new ListRowPresenter.SelectItemViewHolderTask(2));`

No need to implement custom list row presenters or anything

Comment: Same line of code in my onActivityResult gives: IllegalStateException: Cannot start headers transition;  any help?

Answer (score 6):

I've done it when I needed to implement "Return to the first item in a Row by pressing Back".

I was calling this method from Activity's **onBackPressed()**.

If this method returns **false** we call Activity.super.onBackPressed(). 
If **true** - we don't.

```
    public boolean onBackPressed(){
        boolean consumeBack;

        int selectedRowPosition = getRowsFragment().getSelectedPosition();

        ListRowPresenter.ViewHolder selectedRow = (ListRowPresenter.ViewHolder) getRowsFragment().getRowViewHolder(selectedRowPosition);
        int selectedItemPosition = selectedRow.getSelectedPosition();

        if(selectedItemPosition == 0){
            consumeBack = false;
        } else {
            consumeBack = true;
            getRowsFragment().setSelectedPosition(selectedRowPosition, true, new ListRowPresenter.SelectItemViewHolderTask(0));
        }
        return consumeBack;
}
```

Instead of "0" you can set any position you need.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is suggesting the usage of the latest `androidx.leanback` library.

In your `BrowseSupportFragment` create a class variable of type `HeadersSupportFragment`. After creating your `ArrayObjectAdapter` and using it by `setAdapter()`, call the `getHeadersSupportFragment()`. Then call `getSelectedPosition()` to get the current selected position and store it in `Preferences`. Later, use `setSelectedPosition()` to set the previous position.

Here is an example:

```
private HeadersSupportFragment hsp;  
private ArrayObjectAdapter mRowsAdapter;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ListRowPresenter());
        setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);

        hsp = getHeadersSupportFragment();

        int lastPosition = getSharedPreferences(CONTEXT).getInt(LAST_NUMBER, 0);
        hsp.setSelectedPosition(lastPosition);

}

  @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if(hsp != null){
            getSharedPreferences(CONTEXT).edit().putInt(LAST_NUMBER, hsp.getSelectedPosition()).commit();
         
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `headersState` is enabled, use

```
SelectItemViewHolderTask task = new SelectItemViewHolderTask(positionX)
boolean isSmoothScroll = false // If you need to ignore the animation
task.setSmoothScroll(isSmothScroll)  
setSelectedPosition(positionY, isSmothScroll, task)
```

However, if your `headersState` is disabled, then using this code will cause an exception: `IllegalStateException: Cannot start headers transition`.
In this case you need to use this instead:

```
getRowsSupportFragment().setSelectedPosition(positionY, isSmothScroll, task)
```

The difference between them is whether the `HeadersSupportFragment` is updated or not.